# Remove extra language configuration

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-layout

I regularly switch between US english and danish keyboard layouts using Alt+Shift.

On Windows 7 I simply had an english and a danish configuration and everything worked.

On Windows 10 the english configuration has now been split in two: English with US keyboard and english with DA keyboard. The second one is useless to me. Worse, Alt+Shift does not toggle between all three configurations, so I now have to use the mouse to switch.

How do I get rid of the extra configuration or at least make Alt+Shift work for me?

Comment: Do you see the two keyboard layouts (US keyboard and DA keyboard) in the Settings>Time & Language>Rigion & Language, click on English and you'll see Options. In there under the Keyboards section what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your language configurations in `Settings > Time & language > Region and language`. There you can add/remove your language configurations.

And instead of `Alt+Shift` you'll have to use `Win+Space`. This is default starting Windows 8 I think.

Comment: Alt+Shift actually still works. I just needed to remove an unnecessary configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to remove a "keyboard" configuration, which was part of the US English language configuration in `Settings > Time & language > Region and language`.